# Java long running timer is being consumed by GC

Tags: java, timer, task, long-integer

I have a java.util.Timer and I am scheduling TimerTasks that run every 24 hours at 3:00:00 AM, however after 5-8 days the Timer is consumed by GC and all my tasks are cancelled because the timer instance no longer exists.

How can I prevent this ?

I use:

```
t.schedule(timerTask, date);
```

And then the tasks starts again itself (when the task is executed is also calls method that schedules this task again)

The timer is defined like that:

```
public static Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
```

Comment: The timer will only be consumed by GC if there are no reachable references to it. Do you at any time assign a new value to `t` other than at its initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` variables are part of the `class` where they are defined and are initialized when the class is loaded. The GC may decide at some point (especially when memory is low and more is required for a pending operation) to unload a class that is no longer needed. This is what might happen to you here. You could try to create the `Timer` object as a non static member of a class which is guaranteed to have an instance that is still referenced by the GC.

Comment: Well, yes, but a class will only be unloaded if it is unreachable.  That is what "is not longer needed" really means.  And some if some code in a (reachable) class can use that static, then the class containing the static will be reachable.

Answer (score 6):

If the Timer is declared and created like this:

```
    public static Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
```

then I think there are only two scenarios where the `Timer` can be garbage collected:

1. Somewhere in your application, something is assigning a new value to `t`, causing the previous value to become unreachable.
2. The class containing the `t` declaration has become unreachable and has been unloaded.

The first scenario is by far the most likely, and there is a simple way to avoid it.  Change the declaration to this:

```
   public static final Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
```

The second scenario is only plausible if your application (or maybe, the framework it is using) loads the class dynamically using a classloader that itself becomes unreachable.

Comment: I am 100% sure that there is not anything that would assign new value to the timer.

Comment: Even so, change the declaration to a `final`, so that the compiler knows that nothing should be assigned to it.  If you still have the problem after the change, then you know the problem is something else.

Comment: I have created new Timer class, it is basically a class that extends java.util.Timer but I have added public void finalize()... method so I know when the garbage collectors eats the timer for a dinner.

Comment: Have you followed my advice yet?

Comment: Nope because I cannot change it to final because of this annoying error I had to create "restart" command to my app of all the tasks from another class, so I cannot have it final cause I have console command to restart the timer and all scheduled tasks.

Comment: Well if you can't change it to `final` then you will have to find what is causing it the assignment to `t`, because there this no doubt in my mind that is what is happening.  (Not withstanding your "100% sure" ...)

Comment: In my IDE (Eclipse) you can just try to comment out the declaration of the timer you will see the error lines where the variable is used and I have checked that only use of this class is t.schedule(...).

Comment: Perhaps it is not your code doing it.  Perhaps it is JNI code.  Perhaps it is reflective code.  Perhaps it is being done using Unsafe. Pwrhaves something is calling `finalize` directly.  (Yuck!)  Etcetera.  You should NOT be 100% certain if that is your sole reason for believing that.  At a minimum you should check what the variable contains when the object is finalized.